# por que es indefinidos?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un test en Codility y tienen su propio ambiente. Estoy haciendo este test:

> Write a function: function solution(A);
> that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.
> For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.
> Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.
> Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Asi que hice este código

```
function solution(A) {
  A.sort(); // 1 1 2 3 4 6  R=5
  var sig = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  var result = 0;

  A.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (A[index] > 0) {
      sig = A[index + 1];
      sum = A[index] + 1;
      console.log("presente ", A[index], "sig", sig, "suma ", sum);
      if ((sum < sig && A[index] != sig) || (sum > sig && A[index] != sig)) {
        console.log("retorna suma", sum, "<", "siguiente", sig);
        return sum;
      }
    } else {
      console.log("entra >0");
      result = 1;
      return result;
    }
  });
}
```

Y en la consola de mi buscar me retorna esto:

[image: Mi consola]

Si vemos bien en mi consola si me retorna el reultado que es 5, pero en el ambiente de Codility me aparece asi:

[image: Consola de codility]

Los resultados aparecen como indefinidios y no se que hacer!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes unos pocos errores en el código:

- Primero, añadir un `return` a la función que pasas al método `Array.forEach` no hace nada: es totalmente ignorado.
- Quizá pensabas que esos `return` finalizarían tanto el `forEach` como la función `solution`, porque esta última no tiene ningún `return`, por lo que siempre devuelve `undefined`.

Por otro lado, la lógica que estás usando es innecesariamente compleja, se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```js
function solution(array) {
  //quitamos los números negativos y lo ordenamos (el array original no se modifica)
  const aux = array.filter(a => a > 0).sort();
  console.log(aux.toString());
 
  //como está ordenado de menor a mayor, empezamos con el 1 y, si nos lo encontramos, sumamos 1 y miramos el siguiente elemento.
  return aux.reduce((result,item) => result === item? result+1 : result, 1);
}

console.log(solution([-1,4,2,1,-9,9]));
console.log(solution([-1,4,2,1,-3,3,4,6]))
```

#### Pequeña explicación sobre el código

El método [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), como su nombre indica, *reduce* o resume el array a un único valor. Por ejemplo, `[1,2,3].reduce((a,b) -> return a + b)` sumaría todos los elementos y devolvería 6.
La función que se le pasa a reduce recibe como primer parámetro el valor acumulado y como segundo parámetro el elemento actual (se ejecutará una vez para cada elemento del array. Pero hay que saber que este método puede recibir un segundo parámetro que es el valor inicial del "acumulador. En el caso de que este parámetro no se use, entonces en la primera iteración se usa el primer valor como acumulado y el segundo como primer valor:

```js
const suma = (a, b) => {
  console.log('Recibo', a, 'y' ,b);
  return a + b;
}
console.log([1,2,3].reduce(suma));
console.log([1,2,3].reduce(suma, 0));
console.log([1,2,3].reduce(suma, 100));
```

Por otro lado, la función que le paso a reduce se podría escribir también así:

```
return aux.reduce((acumulado, item) => {
  if (acumulado === item) {
  //el valor del item es igual al mínimo que teníamos, así que no nos sirve
  //sumamos uno
    return result+1;
  }
  return result;
}, 1); //valor inicial: 1
```

Es decir, miro si 1 está en el array (que, como está ordenado y no tiene enteros negativos ni ceros, debería ser el primer valor que me encuentre). Si está, sumo uno y miro si 2 está en el resto del array. Si lo encuentro, vuelvo a sumar 1 y sigo comprobando... hasta llegar al final del array y devuelvo el valor final obtenido.

Esta búsqueda se podría optimizar usando un bucle normal que parase en cuanto encontremos un item que cumpla `acumulado < item`, ya que significaría que hemos encontrado un "hueco" (un número que no está) y todos los valores que quedan son mayores, pero para arrays de unos pocas decenas de números no vale la pena el esfuerzo.

Comment: eres una maquina! hiciste en 5 lineas lo que yo en 30 XD, pero no me queda muy claro que hace el return ¿me podrias explicar?

Comment: Claro, ahora pongo una explicación